# Go directly into another tableview's child segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm not really sure how should I ask this, so if any more details are needed, please ask in the comment.

I have an `UITableView`, which has a list of cells that the user can click on, and segue into other `ViewContorller`s. This all works fine, now I need to know if it's possible to go directly into the one of its cell's segue without even displaying the TableView (list) at all.

e.g.:

```
Now: 
         Click                                Click
View A --------> View B (TableView as List) --------> View X (Cell's Segue)

After:
         Click                           Done with the cells
View A --------> View X (Cell's Segue) -->->->-> View B (TableView as List)
```

I asked this because I've made all the necessary codes that were needed to prepare for the cell segue (**View X**) all within **View B**. If I called the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` from **View B**, no matter where I did it, it will always wait till the view was loaded before it goes to **View X**.

I knew that I could move those codes into **View A** but it would mean a complete rewrite of the current flow. If there's a way that I can somehow **NOT** displaying the **View B** but have it prepared for the cell segue, it would be much easier.

**EDIT:**

I do not want to just skip **B** and go directly from **A** to **X**. (I already know I could.) I wanted to know if it's possible to got **through B** but make the process not visible, just looked like it goes from **A** to **X**.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is use array that is use for create table view after all detail that are display in table is from array only

like

```
View A ----->View B----->call function in view did load (like test())--->  match detail from A to array in function test() ----> if true get that specific object and send detail to View X.
```

Here we use array detail use to populate table in **View B** but if it is possible in your code you can use that array in **View A** only and implement method in **View A** to go to **View X** . so there is no need to call **View B**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what you were trying to say and I already use the array object in `View A` to generate data for both `View B and X` now. I doubt there's a way but still wanted to know (because it'd been a painfully process to do so) if what I asked is possible (simply not showing the view and go directly into X). I'll wait for a few more days and see if such options did exist.

Comment: is it possible to have your array in view A than it is possible as I mention in my answer.

Comment: By skipping B and go directly to X is not what I was asking, sorry if I didn't make that clear enough. (my bad) What I wanted is go through B but make the process not visible. It's more than just an array or data passing issue, otherwise I wouldn't even ask on SO. (that would be a dupe.)